# How to make the screen adapt when you use a freeform simulated size in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am making an app and I have a UIScroll view in my viewController. I have set the simulated size to freeform and the height to 2000 and width to 375. When I run my app on the Iphone 7 There are no problems. But when I try to run the app on the iphone 7plus the screen does not adapt and i get these white bars on the right side because my contents width is only 375 pixels. So how can I make my screen to automatically go bigger when I use a bigger device?

Comment: You're wrong. The simulated size is irrelevant. The size of the view _always_ adapts. It's your subviews that are not adapting, because you didn't use autolayout. Learn about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If not already done, you should add contraints (trailing, leading, top space, bottom space) to your `UIScrollView` to pin it to the superview bounds.